# Different Facebook LIKE and SEND message/description

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml, fbconnect, facebook-sharer

I'm using the [Facebook like button code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) on my website, however, I was wondering if it's possible to have different message for LIKE and SEND.

I know the description is pulled from the meta tag as such:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="this is a description about your page you are sharing." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the `href` for the **[send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)** and the **[like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)** buttons point at different URLs, i.e. http://example.com/your-page?ref=like and http://example.com/your-page?ref=send.

You then render your page with a different `og:description` according to the `ref` parameter.

Comment: But how can I get the SEND button to use a different URL to the LIKE one. I'm using the facebook like button generator. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Did you even read my answer and the link you sent me? It's right there, the first form input, **URL to Like**.

Comment: Yes. I used that, and it only lets me put in 1 URL field. You can only generate a LIKE/SEND or LIKE ONLY button, theres no option to generate a SEND ONLY button.

Comment: When you say render the page with a different og:description, does it have to be server-side? would js solution work?

Comment: JS solution would **not** work. The Facebook crawler, the entity responsible for reading the Open Graph tags, does not execute Javascript.